# Web Connector error "Authentication Failed"

Tags: java, quickbooks

I have been attempting to create a simple web service capable of connecting to the Quickbooks web connector with quickbooks 2012 on windows 7.

The implementation is clearly described in the programming guide (http://developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/doc/pdf/qbwc_proguide.pdf).

I keep getting the same error as "Authentication Failed" and "Object reference not set to instance of Object" at the authenticate method. I first created the sample web service in java using Eclipse.

The problem is in the authenticate method.

I also turn on the VERBOSE mode for Web Connector.

Below is the Complete Log

```
    20120924.15:11:25 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ConnectToQB() : Connecting to QuickBooks...

    20120924.15:11:25 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ConnectToQB() : Connected., Session started

    20120924.15:11:25 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.deleteFileIDValueFromQB() : Deleting FileID value from Company object for the ownerID = {57F3B9B1-86F1-4fcc-B1EE-566DE1813D10}

    20120924.15:11:25 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.deleteFileIDValueFromQB() : XML dump follows: -



    <?xml version="1.0"?><?qbxml version="11.0"?><QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError"><DataExtDelRq requestID="1"><DataExtDel><OwnerID>{57F3B9B1-86F1-4fcc-B1EE-566DE1813D10}</OwnerID><DataExtName>FileID</DataExtName><OtherDataExtType>Company</OtherDataExtType></DataExtDel></DataExtDelRq></QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>



    20120924.15:11:25 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.registerDataExtInQB() : XML dump follows: -



    <?xml version="1.0" ?>

    <QBXML>

    <QBXMLMsgsRs>

    <DataExtDelRs requestID="1" statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">

    <DataExtDelRet>

    <OwnerID>{57F3B9B1-86F1-4fcc-B1EE-566DE1813D10}</OwnerID>

    <DataExtName>FileID</DataExtName>

    <TimeDeleted>2012-09-24T20:41:25+05:30</TimeDeleted>

    </DataExtDelRet>

    </DataExtDelRs>

    </QBXMLMsgsRs>

    </QBXML>





    20120924.15:11:25 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.DisconnectFromQB() : Session ended and connection closed

    20120924.15:11:25 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.deleteFileIDValueFromQB() : Data extension FileID has been cleared from QuickBooks for owner id.

    20120924.15:11:25 UTC : RemoveApp() : Application PratikWS has been removed.

    20120924.15:11:29 UTC : QWCReader.ParseQWC() : Contents of QWC file: -

    <QBWCXML>

      <AppName>PratikWS</AppName>

      <AppID></AppID>

      <AppURL>http://localhost:8080/TestWS/services/TestHello?WSDL</AppURL>

      <AppDescription>A short description for WCWebService1</AppDescription>

      <AppSupport>http://localhost:8080</AppSupport>

      <UserName>pratik</UserName>

      <OwnerID>{57F3B9B1-86F1-4fcc-B1EE-566DE1813D10}</OwnerID>

      <FileID>{90A44FB5-33D9-4815-AC85-BC87A7E7D1FB}</FileID>

      <QBType>QBFS</QBType>

      <Scheduler>

        <RunEveryNMinutes>2</RunEveryNMinutes>

      </Scheduler>

    </QBWCXML>

    20120924.15:11:29 UTC : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.ReadQWC(QWCReader QWC) : Parsing application configuration xml file to load its content to variables

    20120924.15:11:30 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.createRegKey() : Error creating registry key for appName = <>

    20120924.15:11:30 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.createRegKey() : Reason: Value cannot be null.

    Parameter name: name

    20120924.15:11:30 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.SerializeToRegistry() : Error saving PratikWS to Registry: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

    20120924.15:11:30 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ConnectToQB() : Connecting to QuickBooks...

    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ConnectToQB() : Connected., Session started

    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.AddToQuickBooks() : Application name = PratikWS

    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.AddToQuickBooks() : Querying company file to find if owner/file id exists.

    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.findFileIDinQB() : Latest QBXML version supported = v11.0

    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.findFileIDinQB() : Querying QuickBooks for existance of owner/file id

    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.findFileIDinQB() : XML dump follows: -



    <?xml version="1.0"?><?qbxml version="11.0"?><QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError"><DataExtDefQueryRq requestID="1"><OwnerID>{57F3B9B1-86F1-4fcc-B1EE-566DE1813D10}</OwnerID></DataExtDefQueryRq></QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>



    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.findFileIDinQB() : XML dump follows: -



    <?xml version="1.0" ?>

    <QBXML>

    <QBXMLMsgsRs>

    <DataExtDefQueryRs requestID="1" statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">

    <DataExtDefRet>

    <OwnerID>{57F3B9B1-86F1-4FCC-B1EE-566DE1813D10}</OwnerID>

    <DataExtName>AppLock</DataExtName>

    <DataExtType>STR255TYPE</DataExtType>

    <AssignToObject>Company</AssignToObject>

    </DataExtDefRet>

    <DataExtDefRet>

    <OwnerID>{57F3B9B1-86F1-4FCC-B1EE-566DE1813D10}</OwnerID>

    <DataExtName>FileID</DataExtName>

    <DataExtType>STR255TYPE</DataExtType>

    <AssignToObject>Company</AssignToObject>

    </DataExtDefRet>

    </DataExtDefQueryRs>

    </QBXMLMsgsRs>

    </QBXML>





    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.findFileIDinQB() : Status message: Status OK

    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.registerDataExtInQB() : Creating DataExtDef named AppLock assigned to Company object for the ownerID = {57F3B9B1-86F1-4fcc-B1EE-566DE1813D10}

    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.registerDataExtInQB() : XML dump follows: -



    <?xml version="1.0"?><?qbxml version="11.0"?><QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError"><DataExtDefAddRq requestID="1"><DataExtDefAdd><OwnerID>{57F3B9B1-86F1-4fcc-B1EE-566DE1813D10}</OwnerID><DataExtName>AppLock</DataExtName><DataExtType>STR255TYPE</DataExtType><AssignToObject>Company</AssignToObject></DataExtDefAdd></DataExtDefAddRq></QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>



    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.registerDataExtInQB() : XML dump follows: -



    <?xml version="1.0" ?>

    <QBXML>

    <QBXMLMsgsRs>

    <DataExtDefAddRs requestID="1" statusCode="3100" statusSeverity="Error" statusMessage="The name "AppLock" of the list element is already in use." />

    </QBXMLMsgsRs>

    </QBXML>





    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.registerDataExtInQB() : Data extension definition has been created in QuickBooks for owner id.

    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.AddToQuickBooks() : Registered the AppLock to company file successfully.

    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.findFileIDValueinQB() : Latest QBXML version supported = v11.0

    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.findFileIDValueinQB() : Querying QuickBooks for existance of owner/file id

    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.findFileIDValueinQB() : XML dump follows: -



    <?xml version="1.0"?><?qbxml version="11.0"?><QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError"><CompanyQueryRq requestID="1"><OwnerID>{57F3B9B1-86F1-4fcc-B1EE-566DE1813D10}</OwnerID></CompanyQueryRq></QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>



    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.findFileIDValueinQB() : XML dump follows: -



    <?xml version="1.0" ?>

    <QBXML>

    <QBXMLMsgsRs>

    <CompanyQueryRs requestID="1" statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">

    <CompanyRet>

    <IsSampleCompany>false</IsSampleCompany>

    <CompanyName>krazykoder</CompanyName>

    <LegalCompanyName>krazykoder</LegalCompanyName>

    <FirstMonthFiscalYear>January</FirstMonthFiscalYear>

    <FirstMonthIncomeTaxYear>January</FirstMonthIncomeTaxYear>

    <CompanyType>InformationTechnologyComputersSoftware</CompanyType>

    <TaxForm>Form1040</TaxForm>

    <SubscribedServices>

    <Service>

    <Name>QuickBooks Online Banking</Name>

    <Domain>banking.qb</Domain>

    <ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>

    </Service>

    <Service>

    <Name>QuickBooks Online Billing</Name>

    <Domain>billing.qb</Domain>

    <ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>

    </Service>

    <Service>

    <Name>QuickBooks Online Billing Level 1 Service</Name>

    <Domain>qbob1.qbn</Domain>

    <ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>

    </Service>

    <Service>

    <Name>QuickBooks Online Billing Level 2 Service</Name>

    <Domain>qbob2.qbn</Domain>

    <ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>

    </Service>

    <Service>

    <Name>QuickBooks Online Billing Payment Service</Name>

    <Domain>qbobpay.qbn</Domain>

    <ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>

    </Service>

    <Service>

    <Name>QuickBooks Bill Payment</Name>

    <Domain>billpay.qb</Domain>

    <ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>

    </Service>

    <Service>

    <Name>QuickBooks Online Billing Paper Mailing Service</Name>

    <Domain>qbobpaper.qbn</Domain>

    <ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>

    </Service>

    <Service>

    <Name>QuickBooks Payroll Service</Name>

    <Domain>payroll.qb</Domain>

    <ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>

    </Service>

    <Service>

    <Name>QuickBooks Basic Payroll Service</Name>

    <Domain>payrollbsc.qb</Domain>

    <ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>

    </Service>

    <Service>

    <Name>QuickBooks Basic Disk Payroll Service</Name>

    <Domain>payrollbscdisk.qb</Domain>

    <ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>

    </Service>

    <Service>

    <Name>QuickBooks Deluxe Payroll Service</Name>

    <Domain>payrolldlx.qb</Domain>

    <ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>

    </Service>

    <Service>

    <Name>QuickBooks Premier Payroll Service</Name>

    <Domain>payrollprm.qb</Domain>

    <ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>

    </Service>

    <Service>

    <Name>Basic Plus Federal</Name>

    <Domain>basic_plus_fed.qb</Domain>

    <ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>

    </Service>

    <Service>

    <Name>Basic Plus Federal and State</Name>

    <Domain>basic_plus_fed_state.qb</Domain>

    <ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>

    </Service>

    <Service>

    <Name>Basic Plus Direct Deposit</Name>

    <Domain>basic_plus_dd.qb</Domain>

    <ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>

    </Service>

    <Service>

    <Name>Merchant Account Service</Name>

    <Domain>mas.qbn</Domain>

    <ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>

    </Service>

    </SubscribedServices>

    <AccountantCopy>

    <AccountantCopyExists>false</AccountantCopyExists>

    </AccountantCopy>

    <DataExtRet>

    <OwnerID>{57F3B9B1-86F1-4fcc-B1EE-566DE1813D10}</OwnerID>

    <DataExtName>AppLock</DataExtName>

    <DataExtType>STR255TYPE</DataExtType>

    <DataExtValue>UNLOCKED:ADMIN-PC</DataExtValue>

    </DataExtRet>

    </CompanyRet>

    </CompanyQueryRs>

    </QBXMLMsgsRs>

    </QBXML>





    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.enterDataExtValueInQB() : XML dump follows: -



    <?xml version="1.0"?><?qbxml version="11.0"?><QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError"><DataExtAddRq requestID="1"><DataExtAdd><OwnerID>{57F3B9B1-86F1-4fcc-B1EE-566DE1813D10}</OwnerID><DataExtName>FileID</DataExtName><OtherDataExtType>Company</OtherDataExtType><DataExtValue>{90A44FB5-33D9-4815-AC85-BC87A7E7D1FB}</DataExtValue></DataExtAdd></DataExtAddRq></QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>



    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.enterDataExtValueInQB() : XML dump follows: -



    <?xml version="1.0" ?>

    <QBXML>

    <QBXMLMsgsRs>

    <DataExtAddRs requestID="1" statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">

    <DataExtRet>

    <OwnerID>{57F3B9B1-86F1-4FCC-B1EE-566DE1813D10}</OwnerID>

    <DataExtName>FileID</DataExtName>

    <DataExtType>STR255TYPE</DataExtType>

    <DataExtValue>{90A44FB5-33D9-4815-AC85-BC87A7E7D1FB}</DataExtValue>

    </DataExtRet>

    </DataExtAddRs>

    </QBXMLMsgsRs>

    </QBXML>





    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.enterDataExtValueInQB() : Data extension value has been created in QuickBooks for FileID

    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.CompanyFileLock.Send_DataExtDefAddRqXML() : XML dump follows: -



    <?xml version="1.0"?><?qbxml version="11.0"?><QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError"><DataExtDefAddRq requestID="1"><DataExtDefAdd><OwnerID>{57F3B9B1-86F1-4fcc-B1EE-566DE1813D10}</OwnerID><DataExtName>AppLock</DataExtName><DataExtType>STR255TYPE</DataExtType><AssignToObject>Company</AssignToObject></DataExtDefAdd></DataExtDefAddRq></QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>



    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.CompanyFileLock.Send_DataExtDefAddRqXML() : XML dump follows: -



    <?xml version="1.0" ?>

    <QBXML>

    <QBXMLMsgsRs>

    <DataExtDefAddRs requestID="1" statusCode="3100" statusSeverity="Error" statusMessage="The name "AppLock" of the list element is already in use." />

    </QBXMLMsgsRs>

    </QBXML>





    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.CompanyFileLock.Send_DataExtAddRqXML() : XML dump follows: -



    <?xml version="1.0"?><?qbxml version="11.0"?><QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError"><DataExtAddRq requestID="1"><DataExtAdd><OwnerID>{57F3B9B1-86F1-4fcc-B1EE-566DE1813D10}</OwnerID><DataExtName>AppLock</DataExtName><OtherDataExtType>Company</OtherDataExtType><DataExtValue>UNLOCKED:ADMIN-PC</DataExtValue></DataExtAdd></DataExtAddRq></QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>



    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.CompanyFileLock.Send_DataExtAddRqXML() : XML dump follows: -



    <?xml version="1.0" ?>

    <QBXML>

    <QBXMLMsgsRs>

    <DataExtAddRs requestID="1" statusCode="3180" statusSeverity="Error" statusMessage="There was an error when saving a data extension named "AppLock".  QuickBooks error message: Attribute with specified name already exists." />

    </QBXMLMsgsRs>

    </QBXML>





    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.AddToQuickBooks() : Application PratikWS has been added to QuickBooks.

    20120924.15:11:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.DisconnectFromQB() : Session ended and connection closed

    20120924.15:11:39 UTC : gridControl1_CheckBoxClicked() : Scheduling has been disabled for PratikWS

    20120924.15:11:41 UTC : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : updateWS() for application = 'PratikWS' has STARTED

    20120924.15:11:41 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.getUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock = FALSE

    20120924.15:11:41 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to True

    20120924.15:11:41 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session locked *********************

    20120924.15:11:41 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.

    20120924.15:11:41 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: PratikWS

    20120924.15:11:41 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): PratikWS

    20120924.15:11:41 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: http://localhost:8080/TestWS/services/TestHello?WSDL

    20120924.15:11:41 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().

    20120924.15:11:41 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Actual error received from web service for serverVersion call: <No such operation 'serverVersion'>. For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-serverVersion.

    20120924.15:11:41 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : This application does not contain support for serverVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.

    20120924.15:11:41 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:<productVersion="2.1.0.27">

    20120924.15:11:41 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : Actual error received from web service for clientVersion call: <No such operation 'clientVersion'>. For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-clientVersion.

    20120924.15:11:41 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application does not contain support for clientVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.

    20120924.15:11:41 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'PratikWS', username = 'pratik'

    20120924.15:11:41 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:<userName="pratik"><password=<MaskedForSecurity>

    20120924.15:11:41 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.

    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

    More info:

    StackTrace =    at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_authenticate(String& ticket, String& companyFileName)

    Source = QBWebConnector

    20120924.15:11:41 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False

    20120924.15:11:41 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************

    20120924.15:11:41 UTC : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : Update completed with errors. See log (QWClog.txt) for details.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong namespace for your SOAP service. Fix your namespace issues, and post your code if you continue to have trouble.

Your namespace should be:
http://developer.intuit.com/

That makes me think that you likely didn't generate this from the WSDL either, which would probably solve your issues.

Comment: This was also already answered in your other thread: https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=56&threadid=18472&enterthread=y

Comment: STILL I AM GETTING "Authentication Failed"
and in the Log "Object reference not set to an instance of Object" error.

Comment: do you know How to change Namespace in Eclipse??